# Add a variable to a Dart extension method or datatype?

Tags: dart

I am converting some JS code to Dart. The JS code adds some properties to an Array.

Example adding 'start' property to the Array.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
a.start = 3;
```

As there is a lot of this code and I'm trying to stay in line with the original JS code as much as possible, I'm trying to find a similar solution in Dart.

I've looked at extensions on types, eg the following, but not sure if they can work for variables and only work for methods ?

```
extension JSList<T> on List<T> { 
  int _start;
  int get start => _start;
  void set start(x) => _start = x;
}
```

But I seem to get various errors like

`Error: Extensions can't declare instance fields`

And looking at the docs, I'm not sure what I'm trying is allowed.

So is there any way to add some custom field/variables/properties to an existing List datatype ? Or are there any other similar suggestions ?

Comment: You can make `_start` static, see here for more info.: https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=extension_declares_instance_field#extension_declares_instance_field

Comment: Thanks, that produces no error, but I need the variable to be different for each list rather than static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dart extension methods are syntactic sugar for freestanding functions to look like instance method calls.  You therefore cannot directly use them to add independent data members to objects.

In some cases, you could have the extension method use an [`Expando`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Expando-class.html) to associate the corresponding `this` object to the desired data:

```dart
extension JSList<T> on List<T> {
  static final _startValues = Expando<int>();

  int get start => _startValues[this] ?? 0;
  set start(int x) => _startValues[this] = x;
}
```

Note that `Expando` has some restrictions about what types can be used as the key.  See the `Expando` documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. Is there a danger at all of memory leak with this method where elements in _startValues are never released if the object has gone out of scope for example ?

Comment: @Ian As long as the key type (in this case, the type you're adding an extension for) isn't one of the types mentioned in the `Expando` documentation and isn't `const`, the the element in the `Expando` should be released when the object is no longer referenced anywhere else. (And `const` objects can stay alive forever anyway, so keeping the corresponding `Expando` element alive seems appropriate.)